# How to solve this rich snippets ratings?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I have found this code for rich snippets:

```
<div itemscope itemtype=”http://schema.org/Product”>
 <img itemprop=”image” src=”image-link.jpg” alt=”Product Name“/>
  <span itemprop=”name”>Product Name</span>
  <div itemprop=”aggregateRating itemscope  
   itemtype=”http://schema.org/AggregateRating”>
  <span itemprop=”ratingValue”>4.5</span>
  out of <span itemprop=”bestRating”>5</span>
 based on <span itemprop=”ratingCount”>301</span> user ratings.
</div>
```

But I don't need ased on `<span itemprop=”ratingCount”>301</span>` user ratings. Because the ratings will be only by the author and it should looks like this picture below:

[image: Google Rich Snippet showing rating stars and reviewer name]

Comment: Note that the markup example contains wrong/invalid quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

in picture that you send, name of reviewer isn't a content author.
but, you can use this code for your content:

```
<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
  <span itemprop="reviewRating">5</span> stars -
  <b>"<span itemprop="name">A masterpiece of literature</span>"</b>
  by <span itemprop="author">John Doe</span>,
  Written on <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2006-05-04">May 4, 2006
  <span itemprop="reviewBody">I really enjoyed this book. It captures the essential
  challenge people face as they try make sense of their lives and grow to adulthood.</span>
</div>
```

and inter auther of article insted of author of reviw

Answer (score 0):

When marking up a review, Google requires that you markup itemReviewed (nest a valid schema type in Review - a type that best describes the item being reviewed). If marking up a rating, Google recommends nesting Rating in Review type via reviewRating and in addition, marking up the rating value (ratingValue).

Sample markup:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
<time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2016-09-04">September 4, 2016</time>
<span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
<span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span>
</span> 
<span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<span itemprop="name">Reviewer's Name</span>
<link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://example.com/reviewers-profile-page"/>
</span>
<span itemprop="description">Snippet from the body of the actual review that captures the author's opinion about the review subject.</span>
<span itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<a itemprop="sameAs" href="http://publishershomepage.com"><span itemprop="name">Publisher's Name</span></a>
</span>
<div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<img itemprop="image" src="product-image.jpg" alt="Product Image"/>
<span itemprop="name">Product Name</span>
</div>
```

See more detailed info about requirements in [Google doc](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews).